# Which is the correct phrase to be used here ? (since, from, was born, born)

Tags: phrases, past-perfect-continuous

Which one of the following is the correct answer sentence ?

**Que:** "Which is your favourite game ?"

**Correct answer phrase ?**

1) "The one I have been playing since the day I born"

2) "The one I have been playing since the day I was born"

3) "The one I have been playing from the day I born"

4) "The one I have been playing from the day I was born"

Comment: @user3169: The question is about usage of "since" vs "from", and "was born" vs "born". That's not proofreading in any fashion or sense, and please do not call it that. If it's not clear enough why the author is having trouble, vote to close as needing more details/unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either #2 or #4 is correct. The verb "to be born" is a very odd verb in English because it exists only in the passive form. So some form of the verb "be" is required.

Comment: The [ODE](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bear) says in a usage note: "Until the 18th century *borne* and *born* were simply variant forms of the past participle of *bear*, used interchangeably with no distinction in meaning. By around 1775, however, the present distinction in use had become established. At that time *borne* became the standard past participle[...]; *born* became restricted to just one very common use, which remains the case today: in the passive, without by, as the standard, neutral way to refer to birth: *she was born in 1965* [...]."

Comment: + 1 The point is: ***I born*** is a no-go, born, borne, and bear notwithstanding. So, Jeff is right. And "since the day my mother bore me" is not relevant here.